# Ошибка "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder"

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь сделать выборку по id в своем проекте по документации (стоит laravel 5.3).

файл routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/search/propertyprofile/{id}', [
'uses' => 'PropertyProfileController@getPropertyProfile',
'as' => 'sh.search.propertyprofile'
]);
```

В этом роуте я написал адресс первым параметром, потом использую контроллер и экшен и оно должно переходить на указанную вьюху (тут ВСЁ хорошо, если вьюха с кодом вывода Hello world и без параметров)

Дальше я создаю экшен (с параметрами $id и переменная $request), в котором в $properties я заношу данные из модели (где параметр id соответствует переменной $id) и возвращаю вьху (где параметр представления и второй параметр данные из таблицы БД заносятся в $properties)

PropertyProfileController:

```
use App\Property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PropertyProfileController extends Controller
{
public function getPropertyProfile($id,Request $request) {
    $properties = Property::where('id', $id);
    return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}   }
```

модель Property (тут вроде все понятно):

```
class Property extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['id','imagePath', 'title', 'description',  ];
}
```

Во вьюхе я вызываю данные title и imagePath из переменной $properties (в которую они занесены из таблицы БД):

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
   <img src="{{ $properties->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
   <h3>{{ $properties->title }}</h3>
@endsection
```

Выдает ошибку :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$imagePath (View: /var/www/projects/auth.laravel.com/resources/views/sh/propertyprofile.blade.php)
```

Логи апача :

```
"GET /search/propertyprofile/8 HTTP/1.1" 500 43913 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
```

Почему он говорит  неопределенная переменная imagePath??Подскажите, пожалуйста, ГДЕ я ошибся или что в моих суждениях не так....(делал по документации https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: Это что? `$properties = Property::where('id', $id)`

Comment: @vp_arth мне кажется это лень читать доку, от начала и до конца

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле `PropertyProfileController` вы написали условие, но не сделали выборку, правильно будет так:

```
$properties = Property::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Если `id` это ваш PK, то можно просто сделать:

```
$properties = Property::find($id);
```

Comment: laravel lazy-загрузку не умеет что ли?

Comment: Умеет но это тот вариант, тут автор задал условие выборки, но не сказал что делать с запросом, проверить есть ли в базе запись такая (метод exists) или выбрать одну запись с таким параметром(метод first) или выбрать все записи с этим параметром(метод get) и т.п. по этому и ругается билдер, а не модель

Comment: @teran, `where` возвращает builder, ленивая загрузка тут ни при чём. Куда её здесь притулить?

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan, как Вы поняли это мой все тот же момент,просто я дохожу до чего-то определенного и выкладываю в новом вопросе!спасибо огромное, все работает, разобрался что к чему и да, метода ->first(); как раз и не хватало!спасибо еще раз огромное Вам, а так же всем участникам данной дискуссии!

Comment: @Александр да я помню этот код, в этот раз уже получился хороший вопрос со всеми исходящими данными :)

Comment: @vp_arth я не знаком с laravel. поэтому и поинтересовался. При попытке получить, например, итератор для этого билдера, он запрос select не выполнит сам по умолчанию?

Comment: @teran, итераторы коллекций да, lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам использовать `Request $request` в данной функции если оно даже не используется?

```
public function getPropertyProfile($id,Request $request) {
    $properties = Property::where('id', $id);
    return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}
```

Для правильности конечно следует убрать, но если вы намерены его использовать в дальнейшем то лучше поменяйте местами иначе функция не будет работать

```
public function getPropertyProfile(Request $request, $id) {
    $properties = Property::find($id);
    return view('sh.propertyprofile', ['properties' => $properties]);
}
```

Comment: iAxel, спасибо за комментарий и уточнение) П.С.: даже в моем случае оно сработало, буду очень признателен,если Вы объясните мне Ваше уточнение(этот ньюанс), а то я даже с Request-ом толком не разобрался даже.....

Comment: @iAxel "Пиздеш и провокации" :) извините не сдержался :) :) Фишка в том что Laravel парсит параметры! и определяет их тип! ей по барабану на ОЧЕРЕДНОСТЬ!!!

Comment: @iAxel  Даже вот не сдержался [статью](http://slashnode.com/dependency-injection/) нашел :) :) заголовок  Eco-friendly dependency injection, и там чуууть ниже

Comment: @Александр я лишь по документации прошелся, и были моменты когда у меня "звездешь" реально не работало...